# Selected Text of The ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

how can I get the selected text on the SelectionChanged event of the comboBox
here is my code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboRecordType" Margin="2,0" Height="23" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Weight"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Height"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Blood Pressure"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Blood Gulocose"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

cboRecordType.Text is empty, didn't cantain the selected Text, how to get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SelectionChanged` event handler, you can either look at the `cboRecordType.SelectedItem` property on the combobox itself, or you can look at the `AddedItems` property of the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` passed into the event handler.

When an item is selected, the item is added to the `AddedItems` array property of the event args. (multiple items in a multi select case).  When an item is deselected, it is added to the `RemovedItems` array property of the event args.

Comment: it will return following value
{System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Weight}
but I only need the Weight how can I get it

Comment: @Asim - use SelectedItem.Content ?

Comment: @Gishu: didn't see any property of content of SelectedItem

Comment: @Asim - SelectedItem is defined to return an object. You'd need to cast it to a ComboBoxItem, before accessing its Content property to get the string that you want.

Comment: Note that eventargs.AddedItems is the preferred pattern, since it will also support multiselection and it tells you which items are coming into selection and which are losing selection (via the RemovedItems array)

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, you need to handle that event like this code: [ComboBox SelectionChanged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1a0bdd27-7faa-4b56-9900-8740c017781a)
    Code Block

```
/// <summary>

/// Handles the comboBox SelectionChanged event

/// </summary>

/// <param name="sender"></param>

/// <param name="e"></param>

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

{



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handling events, you can try the binding approach. For that you need to create a property like this and bind it to your combobox's selected item

```
private String _selectedItem;
public String SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
    }
}

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

SideNote: You can also fill in some collection and bind it to the combobox instead of hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

Better try using Command and CommandParametar as part of MVVM implementation.